# Python re: Match all the word consisting of letters only

Tags: python, python-re

I just to find all the words in a sentence. I tried the below, but doesn't work. Thanks

```
import re

string1= "This is a nice day - 23 Sep 2019 Oct2021"

word1=re.findall('\b[a-zA-Z]+\b', string1, flags=0)
word2=re.findall('^[a-zA-Z]+$', string1, flags=0)
word3=re.findall('\w+', string1, flags=0)

print(word1) --> []
print(word2) --> []
print(word3) --> ['This', 'is', 'a', 'nice', 'day', '23', 'Sep', '2019', 'Oct2021']
```

**Desired outcome**

['This', 'is', 'a', 'nice', 'day', 'Sep']

Comment: It looks like you are trying to match `[a-zA-Z]+\b`, assuming your language doesn't do diacritics. Your problem is you don't have an `r` in front of the string, causing the `\` to look like an escape

Comment: @Grismar Well, I think it should probably be `\b[a-zA-Z]+\b` instead of `[a-zA-Z]+\b`.

Comment: It's not required, @MartesBerkeley - it will start matching at the first letter regardless.

Answer (score 2):

You were simply missing an `r` to indicate a raw string, leaving the backslashes untouched:

```py
import re

subject = "This is a nice day - 23 Sep 2019 Oct2021"
for match in re.findall(r"[a-zA-Z]+\b", subject):
    print(match)

print(re.findall(r'[a-zA-Z]+\b', subject))
```

Result:

```
This
is
a
nice
day
Sep
['This', 'is', 'a', 'nice', 'day', 'Sep']
```

The `flags = 0` is superfluous.

Since some people insist on adding a starting `\b`, please note that if your text contains elements that start with numbers or other symbols, and then just contain letters which you wouldn't want to match, you should use a leading `\b`:

```
import re

subject = "It all -depends on your 2source text"
print(re.findall(r'[a-zA-Z]+\b', subject))
print(re.findall(r'\b[a-zA-Z]+\b', subject))
```

Output:

```
['It', 'all', 'depends', 'on', 'your', 'source', 'text']
['It', 'all', 'depends', 'on', 'your', 'text']
```

Comment: You should probably have word boundaries on both sides, i.e. use: `\b[a-zA-Z]+\b`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen That's what I thought, too. Although this pattern matches all the given cases, it wouldn't satisfy all `the words consisting of letters only`.

Comment: @MartesBerkeley Your comment is incorrect and `\b[A-Za-z]+\b` will match all letter-only words.